# Poco Logs not correctly displayed in Windows EventViewer

Tags: c++, windows, poco-libraries, event-viewer

I have a simple Application which uses the `Poco::Logger` and the `Poco::EventLogChannel` to write the Log Messages into the Windows EventViewer.

After i run my Program with Administrator Rights, the Registry Keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` are created and the `CategoryMessageFile` and `EventMessageFile` Keys are pointing to the `PocoFoundation.dll` inside the `Windows/System32` Folder. I have copied the `dll` to that location.

But inside the EventViewer the Log Message is displayed but no other informations. It just says:

> The description for Event ID 51001 from source RRWS cannot be found. Either the
> component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the
> installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local
> computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved
> with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> test log message
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message
> table

For me it seems like the EventViewer is not able to find the `dll`.

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you copy the DLL into there "manually" (via `explorer.exe` or `cmd.exe`, which are 64-bit processes) or programmatically from your application? Assuming your application is 32-bit (since you are using `PocoFoundation.dll`, not `PocoFoundation64.dll`), the DLL could end up in a different folder due to [File System Redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) (unless you explicitly specified the `Sysnative` alias to bypass redirection). Also, I think you need to restart the Windows Event Viewer to refresh its list of registered event sources.

Comment: When setting the value in registry, be sure to use `REG_EXPAND_SZ` instead of `REG_SZ` if you use environment variables such as `%SystemRoot%` to define the path, as described in [KB166902](https://learn.microsoft.com/troubleshoot/windows/win32/troubleshoot-event-message-not-found). Anyway, why are you placing your app's DLLs into the system folder? Maybe the installation folder of your app would be a better place?

Comment: @heapunderrun i was just checking if it was in general able to find the dll and so checking different methods.
I tried it with both versions, the `PocoFoundation.dll` and my application building as `32 Bit` and also with the `PocoFoundation64.dll` and my application building as `64 Bit`. I also restarted the PC after registering my Application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem when using the `dlls` builded via `cmake` because the ones builded by `cmake` are only named `PocoFoundationd.dll` and `PocoFoundation.dll` but inside the `EventLogChannel.cpp` in the `setUpRegistry()` Function tries to load the `PocoFoundation64d.dll` as seen here:

```
if (disp == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY)
    {
        std::wstring path;
        #if defined(POCO_DLL)
            #if defined(_DEBUG)
                #if defined(_WIN64)
                    path = findLibrary(L"PocoFoundation64d.dll");
                #else
                    path = findLibrary(L"PocoFoundationd.dll");
                #endif
            #else
                #if defined(_WIN64)
                    path = findLibrary(L"PocoFoundation64.dll");
                #else
                    path = findLibrary(L"PocoFoundation.dll");
                #endif
            #endif
        #endif
```

Also mentioned here: [Poco Issue 3304](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/3304)